# Find a vector equation and parametric equations for the line segment that joins $P$ to $Q$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, 3d

> Find a vector equation and parametric equations for the line segment that joins $P$ to $Q$. Here $P(1,-1,7)$ and $Q(7,5,1)$.

I have tried to find $r(t)$ by using the formula $r(t)=p+t(p-q)$ but it is wrong. I am making a stupid mistake.

Comment: I have tried to find r(t) by using the formula r(t)=p+t(p-q) but it is wrong. I am making a stupid mistake.

Comment: The formula is $r(t) = P + t(Q - P)$..

Comment: Show your work and we can find your mistake.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Apparently the mistake is using (P-Q) instead of (Q-P).

Comment: I got 1i-1j+7k+t(6i+6j-6k)

Comment: @Fundamental: Indeed you are right.  Talha: Add that to your question instead of leaving comments.

Comment: The formula you posted in your last comment is correct. Note that there is more than one correct formula to describe the same line; if your answer is different from textbook's, it does not mean you are wrong.

Comment: This is my first time using this platform, sorry for being a noob. But the answer is still wrong! :/

Comment: How do you know it's wrong?